# Exclude all compiled classes from jar built by gradle java project

Tags: java, gradle, jar

I have a gradle java project with custom task which generates some files during build. I need to produce jar artifact containing ONLY generated files. Problem: **jar contains both generated files and class files**.

Exclusion of *.java files from source sets is impossible because I need compiled classes for generation.

```
jar {
  exclude("**/*.class")
  from ("$buildDir/generated-files-dir")
}
```

Snippet above removes class files but leaves directories as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `includeEmptyDirs = false` to your jar task.

```
jar {
  exclude("**/*.class")
  includeEmptyDirs = false
  from ("$buildDir/generated-files-dir")
}
```

https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:includeEmptyDirs